# which rails voting system gem has the following features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, voting, voting-system

Which rails voting system plugin or gem that has the following features

- vote up &down
- Ability to show net number of votes
- vote for all objects in the model (But only once per object per user)
- list all objects in the model by higher number of votes
- Not to vote on your own object

I have looked at [thumbs up](https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up)  gem,but its not stating clearly,i might be wrong (if i am wrong please correct me).Also i need to know if it is possible to customize thumbs up gem?Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may be what you're after: [make_voteable](https://github.com/medihack/make_voteable)

There are loads of other voting gems available, see ruby-toolbox:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=voting

And yes, you can always fork the code on the 'thumbs up' gem if you'd like to change how it works.

Answer (score 0):

acts_as_votable is a really good gem for the full features you have mentioned

[acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)

Downloawd link : [rubygems acts_as_votable](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_votable)